# YOLOv5 how to detect custom data

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, yolov5

I wanted to do character detection in the game via yolov5
But so far I have just started to study it all
How to train custom data, I know
But I don't know how to tell yolo in the code
so that it detects custom data in the screenshot
that I make using mss, and numpy
and I broadcast these screenshots using cv2.imshow
thanks in advance

I tried different ways, but nothing worked, I looked in the official documentation.
but without success

Comment: Did you check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74593406/18667225 ? If you still have questions please share minimal reproducible code. Please read [ask]!

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using Custom Model

```py
import torch

# Model
# model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'yolov5s')  # or yolov5m, yolov5l, yolov5x, etc.
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', 'path/to/best.pt')  # custom trained model

# Images
im = 'https://ultralytics.com/images/zidane.jpg'  # or file, Path, URL, PIL, OpenCV, numpy, list

# Inference
results = model(im)

# Results
results.print()  # or .show(), .save(), .crop(), .pandas(), etc.

results.xyxy[0]  # im predictions (tensor)
results.pandas().xyxy[0]  # im predictions (pandas)
#      xmin    ymin    xmax   ymax  confidence  class    name
# 0  749.50   43.50  1148.0  704.5    0.874023      0  person
# 2  114.75  195.75  1095.0  708.0    0.624512      0  person
# 3  986.00  304.00  1028.0  420.0    0.286865     27     tie
```

Comment: You can find out more
or an article on this topic

Comment: @ХлебКрутой I recommend if your dataset can be public, you can use Roboflow, Label the Data, then while exporting add some augmentations and then train on Googe Colab. For More Tutorials visit https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5

Comment: understood, but I need a little more information about the line: model = burner.the hub.load ( etc . )

Comment: @ХлебКрутой When you have trained your custom model it will give a `best.pt` model in YOLOv5 directory. Here in the `path/to/best.pt` you specify that path to the best.pt to use your custom model.